# Prevent ignite from updating the cache when calling a setter

Tags: java, ignite

I have an ignite cache version 2.2.0 with the following configuration:

```
final CacheConfiguration<String, Product> cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<>("products");

cacheConfiguration.setName("products");
cacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(String.class, Product.class);
cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
cacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(new FactoryBuilder.SingletonFactory<>( new ProductCacheStoreAdapter()));
cacheConfiguration.setCopyOnRead(false);
cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
cacheConfiguration.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true);

return cacheConfiguration;
```

The product has the following fields:

```
String id;
String brand;
ProductInfos infos;
```

When I now select a product from the cache:

```
log.info("product: ") + igniteCache.get("12345");
```

I get the following:

```
product: 12345, beats, null
```

Now I do the following:

```
product.setProductInfos(new ProductInfos(.......));
log.info("product: ") + igniteCache.get("12345");
```

And I get the following:

```
product: 12345, beats, {....}
```

So that means that by setting the product infos on the product object the cache automatically got updated.

How can I prevent that?

**EDIT**

setting `copyOnRead` to be `true` fixes this issue. but is that the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this effect because of a combination of enabled on-heap cache and disabled `copyOnRead`.

It means, that values are stored on heap and not copied, when inserted to and read from the cache. `copyOnRead` should be disabled only when you don't change values, that are also stored in cache.